# Mongodb in java , how to use date ranges in the aggregates function

Tags: java, database, mongodb, date, isodate

I have the following code for filtering based on sex and then grouping based on employee_id, along with an extra field that does the sum for total of days.

```
    collection.aggregate(
            Arrays.asList(
                    Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("$sex","male")),
              Aggregates.group("$employee_id", sum("total", "$days")),

            )
    ).forEach(printBlock);
```

In this query how do I add a date range to match for example -
greater than (some date) and less than (some date) .
Also which would be the right format of date to use like in java.util.Date or something else.
I found similar questions but nothing in 2020 where there may be an updated part for doing this in an easier way.
Also would there be a way to generate a query without this format and just filter by date range and group by some value.

```
     the json example

                  {
                    "employee_id": "GX078333",
                    "sex": "male",
                    "days": 5,
                    "date": {
                              "$date": "2020-06-01T07:33:50.796Z"
                    },
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match multiple values using **`Filters.and(Bson, Bson, ...)`** or **`Filters.and(List<Bson>)`** **[Reference](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html)**

I hope you know that date must be an array/list of dates.

So, to provide an Example. `cDateRang` is an `ArrayList` with your Dates which should match.

e.g.

```
ArrayList<Date> cDateRange = new ArrayList<>();
cQueryFields.add(Filters.in("date.mydatearray", cDateRange));

//
Bson cQuery = Filters.and(cQueryFields);

//
ArrayList<Bson> cQueryList = new ArrayList<>();
cQueryList.add(Aggregates.match(cQuery));

//
cQueryList.add(Aggregates.match(cQuery));
AggregateIterable<Document> cResult = cMongoDatabase.getCollection("your collection Name").aggregate(pFilter)
```